# How do I get Bumblebee working with a GTX 660M?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a GTX 660M, also an integrated Intel. The Intel runs fine but I couldn't start the Nvidia.

I followed all the steps to install and configure Bumblebee from [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) tutorial and [this](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/182) other tutorial.

This is the output:

```
optirun -vv glxspheres
[  706.315737] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  706.316244] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[  706.444333] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.0.1 starting...
[  706.444367] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  706.444374] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  706.444380] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[  706.444386] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
[  706.444392] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  706.444398] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  708.358088] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to assign any connected display devices to X screen 0
[  708.358117] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to assign any connected display devices to X screen 0
[  708.358125] [DEBUG]Socket closed.<
[  708.358147] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  708.358155] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

---

And this is the `/var/log/Xorg.8.log` file

> [    47.372] 
>  
>   X.Org X Server 1.11.3
>   Release Date: 2011-12-16
>   [    47.372] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
>   [    47.372] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-26-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
>   [    47.372] Current Operating System: Linux babilonia-P170EM 3.2.0-29-generic #46->Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64
>   [    47.372] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
>  >root=UUID=002bd5b6-9931-48ae-8c5e-2ac9bebe653e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
>   [    47.372] Build Date: 04 August 2012  01:51:23AM
>   [    47.372] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.7 (For technical support please see >http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
>   [    47.372] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
>   [    47.372]   Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
>       to make sure that you have the latest version.
>   [    47.372] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
>     (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>     (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
>
>   [    47.372] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.8.log", Time: Tue Aug 21 22:06:06 2012
>
>   [    47.372] (++) Using config file: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia"
>
>   [    47.372] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
>
>   [    47.373] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
>
>   [    47.373] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
>
>   [    47.373] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
>   [    47.373] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
>
>   [    47.373] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
>
>     Using the first device section listed.
>
>   [    47.373] (**) |   |-->Device "Device1"
>   [    47.373] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
>     Using a default monitor configuration.
>   [    47.373] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "false"
>
>   [    47.373] (**) Not automatically adding devices
>   [    47.373] (==) Automatically enabling devices
>   [    47.373] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
>   [    47.373]   Entry deleted from font path.
>   [    47.373] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
>   [    47.373]   Entry deleted from font path.
>   [    47.373] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
>   [    47.373]   Entry deleted from font path.
>   [    47.373] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
>   [    47.373]   Entry deleted from font path.
>   [    47.373] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
>   [    47.373]   Entry deleted from font path.
>   [    47.373] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does >not exist.
>   [    47.373]   Entry deleted from font path.
>   [    47.373] (==) FontPath set to:
>     /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
>     /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
>     built-ins
>   [    47.373] (++) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
>   [    47.373] (==) |-->Input Device ""
>   [    47.373] (==) |-->Input Device ""
>   [    47.373] (==) The core pointer device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
>     Using the default mouse configuration.
>   [    47.373] (==) The core keyboard device wasn't specified explicitly in the layout.
>     Using the default keyboard configuration.
>   [    47.373] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f6a17e02b00
>   [    47.373] (II) Module ABI versions:
>   [    47.373]   X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
>   [    47.373]   X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
>   [    47.373]   X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
>   [    47.373]   X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
>   [    47.374] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0fd4:1558:7102 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216,
>  0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ >0x????????/524288
>   [    47.374] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
>   [    47.374] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
>   [    47.374] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.374]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.374]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
>   [    47.374]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension DPMS
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension XVideo
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
>   [    47.374] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
>   [    47.374] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.374]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.374]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
>   [    47.374]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
>   [    47.374] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
>   [    47.374] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/libglx.so
>   [    47.432] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
>   [    47.432]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.432]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
>   [    47.432] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.37  Wed Aug  8 20:16:03 PDT 2012
>   [    47.432] (II) Loading extension GLX
>   [    47.432] (II) LoadModule: "record"
>   [    47.432] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
>   [    47.432] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.432]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
>   [    47.432]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
>   [    47.432]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
>   [    47.432] (II) Loading extension RECORD
>   [    47.432] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
>   [    47.432] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
>   [    47.432] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.432]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.432]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
>   [    47.432] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
>   [    47.432] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
>   [    47.432] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
>   [    47.432] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.432]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
>   [    47.432]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
>   [    47.433] (II) Loading extension DRI2
>   [    47.433] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
>   [    47.433] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
>   [    47.438] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
>   [    47.438]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.438]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
>   [    47.439] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
>   [    47.440] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/mouse_drv.so
>   [    47.440] (II) Module mouse: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.440]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.7.1
>   [    47.440]   Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
>   [    47.440]   ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
>   [    47.440] (II) LoadModule: "kbd"
>   [    47.440] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module kbd
>   [    47.440] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
>   [    47.440] (II) Unloading kbd
>   [    47.440] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
>   [    47.440] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.37  Wed Aug  8 19:54:47 PDT 2012
>   [    47.440] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
>   [    47.441] (--) using VT number 7
>
> [    47.441] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
>   [    47.441] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
>   [    47.441] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
>   [    47.441] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.441]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.441]   ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
>   [    47.441] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
>   [    47.441] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
>   [    47.442] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
>   [    47.443] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>   [    47.443]   compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
>   [    47.443]   ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
>   [    47.443] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
>   [    47.443] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
>   [    47.443] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
>   [    47.444] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
>   [    47.444] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
>   [    47.444] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
>   [    47.444] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
>     "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
>   [    47.444] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
>   [    47.444] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
>   [    47.444] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
>   [    47.444] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
>   [    47.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "true"
>
>   [    47.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseEDID" "false"
>   [    47.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
>
>   [    47.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
>   [    47.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): ConnectedMonitor string: "DFP"
>
>   [    47.444] (**) NVIDIA(0): Ignoring EDIDs
>   [    48.321] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 660M (GK107) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
>   [    48.321] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 1048576 kBytes
>   [    48.321] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.07.22.00.07
>   [    48.321] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
>   [    48.321] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
>   [    48.324] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GTX 660M at PCI:1:0:0
>   [    48.324] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
>   [    48.324] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
>   [    48.324] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to assign any connected display devices to X screen 0
>   [    48.326] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failing initialization of X screen 0
>   [    48.345] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
>   [    48.345] (II) Unloading nvidia
>   [    48.345] (II) UnloadModule: "wfb"
>   [    48.345] (II) Unloading wfb
>   [    48.345] (II) UnloadModule: "fb"
>   [    48.345] (II) Unloading fb
>   [    48.345] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
>   [    48.345] 
>   Fatal server error:
>   [    48.345] no screens found
>   [    48.345] 
>   Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
>      at http://wiki.x.org
>    for help. 
>   [    48.345] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional >
> information.
>   [    48.345] 
>   [    48.345]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
>   [    48.345] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

Answer (score 2):

The Nvidia GTX 660M video card requires at least [version 302.17 of the proprietary nvidia driver](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/302.17/README/supportedchips.html). You can get a newer driver by adding the ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates PPA and upgrading your nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Edit `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and change `Driver=` to `Driver=nvidia`. If the command `modinfo nvidia-current` says that no module can be found, then change `KernelDriver=nvidia-current` to `KernelDriver=nvidia`. After changing the configuration, either reboot or restart the Bumblebee daemon:

```
sudo restart bumblebeed
```

Note: not making the configuration changes so may cause `optirun` to show the below error message:

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled."
```

Good luck!

Comment: I have installed the driver 304.37; also I changed the bumblebee.conf the output is the same

Comment: Please http://paste.ubuntu.com your `/var/log/Xorg.8.log` file

Answer (score 2):

Finally i fixed it. I'm looking again and [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/182) I found the solution
In `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` change the `Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"` line to `Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"`
:)

Comment: worked nice... what are the consequences on using an external harddrive though?